# Sufficient conditions for uniformly integrable

Tags: probability-theory, expectation, uniform-integrability

I have learned the definition of uniformly integrable and its sufficient and necessary condition:

We call $\{X_n, n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ uniformly integrable, if 
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} \sup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} E(|X_n| 1_{\{|X_n| \geq x\}})=0
$$
And it has a sufficient and necessary condition:

$\{X_n, n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ is uniformly integrable if and only if $\forall \epsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $\forall A$ satisfying $P(A) < \delta$, we have $\sup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} E(|X_n| 1_{A}) < \epsilon$ and $\sup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} E(|X_n|) < \infty$.

I need prove:

If there exists $Y \in L_1$ such that $\forall x > 0$, we have
$$
\sup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} P(|X_n|>x) \leq P(Y>x)
$$
then $\{X_n, n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ is uniformly integrable.

I want to first prove $\sup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} E(|X_n|) < \infty$. I tried this:
\begin{align*}
E|X_n| &= E(|X_n|1_{\{ X_n>x \}}) + E(|X_n|1_{\{ X_n \leq x \}})\\
&\leq E(|X_n|1_{\{ X_n>x \}}) + xP(X_n \leq x)\\
&\leq E(|X_n|1_{\{ X_n>x \}}) + x
\end{align*}
I have difficulty to move on. Could anyone give me some advice? Thank you!

Comment: You will have to use that $$\mathbb{E}(Y) = \int_0^{\infty} \mathbb{P}(Y>r) \, dr$$ for any non-negative random variable $Y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is more straightforward to work with the definition than the equivalent characterisation you give in this case. We have, for $x > 0$,
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[|X_n| 1_{\{|X_n| \geq x\}}] &= \int_x^\infty  \mathbb{P}(|X_n| > y) dy \\&
\leq \int_x^\infty \mathbb{P}(Y>y) dy \\& = \mathbb{E}[Y 1_{\{Y \geq x\}}] \to 0
\end{align*}
as $x \to \infty$ since $Y \in L^1$. Since this bound is true independent of $n$, this gives the desired result.